# Java EE Application Servers and JDK versions need to match certified versions?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, version, java

According to the [Java EE Compatibility page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) JBoss AS 7 [was tested](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/community/jboss-ee6-full-compat-1525034.html) with JDK Java SE 6.0 update 6u30; a coworker says that these are the specifications that are certified to be Java EE compliant so we must use them because that environment is well tested.

I haven't found an argument against this but also haven't found an argument against using JBoss with the JDK 7 ([as they are compatible](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-Requirements)) so I'm asking if this is a common practice or it's just a trivial point? Java 7 language enhancements would be very helpful for our next release cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main argument should be that java 6 has been [EOL'ed by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) and will not be getting any new (freely available) security updates. should you ship a jdk-6-based product some of your customers will definitely complain about it (i know some of the customers of the company i work for routinely scan products they buy and install and notify vendors of any EOL'ed or known-to-be-insecure versions in use).

Comment: otoh there are still a lot of companies hard at work trying to make the switch from 1.4 to 1.5. And a lot more that are trying to upgrade from 1.5 to 1.6.

Comment: yes, but the OP implied that going for 7 is definitely possible. if its possible than in my experience it will make selling it easier

Comment: technically possible or economically? He should investigate his customers, what they want and need, rather than assuming that just because he can he should. And thinking you can can be misleading. We're currently trying to get our (huge) product suit working under 7, and running into bumps and potholes at every turn, mostly in 3rd party libraries we link to, but also some of the JDK core libraries make it incredibly hard to have something that works correctly and identically when it has to operate under a choice of 6 or 7 (rather than forcing either one).

Comment: we ship a fairly large j2ee product, running atop jboss as7. previous version was java 6, current one is 7 and we didnt experience any hitches. ymmv i guess.

Comment: probably depends on what specifically you're using, yes.

Comment: It's both, technically and economically possible to migrate IMO and also it would help us to upgrade to newer versions of JBoss because our current version has bugs that were not fixed until JBoss 6. Also we have a problem related to [JDK 5 and 6 use of zip files](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBVFS-159). I think Java 6 being EOL'ed will be a mayor concern about this.

Answer (score 2):

> so we must use them because that environment is well tested.

I don't feel this in entirely correct. Not rarely is the certification done for a beta version of a product (e.g. [Geronimo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/community/apache-ger-ee6-full-tested-config-1376611.html)) or an older version containing many bugs (e.g. [JBoss](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/community/jboss-ee6-full-compat-1525034.html)).

Passing the TCK is a very basic test of Java EE compliance. It's unfortunately NOT a test that demonstrates overall stability or suitability for production. Vendors release new versions of their certified product all the time, which contain many bug fixes. Those releases are rarely re-certified, but of course those are nearly always the recommended versions to use.

Go with what the vendor recommends to use in production, and don't stare too much at the configuration that was used for spec certification.